# Почему в конструкторе нет типа данных "Форматированный текст"?

Tags: access, ms-access

Используется Access - 2016
Если создавать форматируемое поле через таблицу, то:
    - выбираем **"Форматированный текст"** и создаётся форматируемое поле без проблем;
   - но в конструкторе созданное поле имеет тип данных - **"Длинный текст"**;

Если создавать форматируемое поле через конструктор, то:
 - во первых отсутствует тип **"Форматированный текст"**;
 - во вторых если выбирать **"Длинный текст"**, то создаётся не форматируемое поле;

Как через конструктор можно создать форматируемое поле?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить встроенной справке (правда, у меня под рукой 2007), то

> В Microsoft Office Access 2007 возможно хранение форматируемого текста в базе данных. Для этого используется поле MEMO, а для свойства Формат текста устанавливается значение Формат RTF. Можно применить форматирование ко всему содержимому или к части поля, редактируя поле в форме с помощью присоединенного элемента управления или при отображении поля в таблице. Можно также применить форматирование ко всему полю при просмотре отчета в режиме макета.

Вряд ли что-то сильно поменялось в новой версии, если не считать того, что название "Длинный текст" сменило название "поле MEMO".

> В предыдущих версиях Access тип данных "Поле MEMO" использовался для хранения больших объемов текста, а тип данных "Текстовый" — для хранения более коротких строк (до 255 символов). В Access 2013 и 2016 эти два типа данных переименованы в "Длинный текст" и "Короткий текст" соответственно.

[Оригинал](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%E2%80%94-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-MEMO-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5)

Попробуйте обратиться к встроенной справке своей версии Access за уточнениями.

Comment: Да. Действительно заработало... Решение "для свойства Формат текста устанавливается значение Формат RTF."